# Serverless Framework | How to use wildcard (*) in prefix path

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I'm using Serverless Framework to create an S3 Lambda trigger:

```
functions:
  profilePictureInput:
    handler: triggers/handler.profilePictureInput
    memorySize: 10240
    timeout: 25
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: ${self:custom.mediaInputBucketName}
          existing: true
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: private/*/profile-pictures
```

**Question:** Is it possible to use a wildcard in the prefix path?

I want the lambda to be triggered if object key is `private/foo/profile-pictures` or `private/bar/profile-pictures`.

The above example does not seem to work (lambda not triggered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

> Because the wildcard asterisk character (*) is a valid character that
> can be used in object key names, Amazon S3 literally interprets the
> asterisk as a prefix or suffix filter. You can't use the wildcard
> character to represent multiple characters for the prefix or suffix
> object key name filter.

You have to register all prefix value strings to the S3 event. For you case, it will look like this:

```
functions:
  profilePictureInput:
    handler: triggers/handler.profilePictureInput
    memorySize: 10240
    timeout: 25
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: ${self:custom.mediaInputBucketName}
          existing: true
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: private/foo/profile-pictures
            - prefix: private/bar/profile-pictures
```

Comment: Would 'prefix: /profile-pictures" also trigger object with key "private/foo/profile-pictures"?

Comment: @Vingtoft No, `prefix` should be the prefix of an object path.